# how to replace T-SQL CASE statement with efficient code

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

how can i replace the following case statement with efficient code

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN LEN(Code.Description)>=30
    THEN left(Code.Description, 30) + '...' 
    ELSE NominalCode.Description END AS ShortDescription
FROM Code
```

Because the data set it returns is going to be 30-50,000 records and according to lead dev this code is ridiculous. I need help

Comment: The lead dev didn't give you any other direction to go?

Comment: @arjabbar. this is his statement "mate.. sql server is so rich, no need to write that ridiculous case stmt
think about size of the data you return, and find a better way to truncate that field"

Comment: case statements ARE efficient code.

Comment: What was his complaint?  And if it was just a blanket "this is ridiculous" then he in't much of a dev.  (let alone a lead).  You could create a computed column with the reduced data but really for 50k records this isn't going to be a bottle neck.

Comment: What datatype is `Description`?

Comment: If you need the first 30 characters of a field with ellipsis added, than `LEFT()` is the right tool.

Comment: @MatthewWhited. unfortunately I cannot argue with him as he is the tech lead of the team

Comment: I am very curious as to what code your lead would offer instead.

Comment: Without restructing the database there isn't really anything faster than what you coded.

Comment: @MatthewWhited. nvarchar(50)

Comment: @MatthewWhited. This gives me hope that my code was not bad. Thanks

Comment: Sounds like some holy war is going on in this shop. I would stay away of those politics, especially this `case` is perfectly fine.

Comment: Is he concerned about the else part in the CASE as it is derived from another table....could you please provide the full query? Otherwise it looks good!

Comment: You aren't going to get any faster. `nvarchar(50)` will be stored in with the rest of the field data in the database row.  If it was `text` or `nvarchar(max)` you would probably want to restructure the data.  You could always return the entire value then do the truncate on the client. but that's not the same.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you intend:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN LEN(c.Description) > 30
             THEN left(c.Description, 30) + '...' 
             ELSE c.Description
        END) AS ShortDescription
FROM Code c;
```

That is, the `Description` column references all come from the same table.  Your code is fine.

However, I would adjust the semantics so the resulting string always has the same length:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN LEN(c.Description) > 30
             THEN LEFT(c.Description, 27) + '...' 
             ELSE c.Description
        END) AS ShortDescription
FROM Code c;
```

Comment: I'd also drop the equals as it would be 30 char either way

Comment: Notice how in the original question he selects a different field if the length is less than 30 chars?

Comment: @ajeh . . . That is the first point in my answer.  Given the `from` clause in the OP's question, it is presumably the same table.

Answer (score 1):

Other than adding a ShortDesc field to your Product Table, perhaps I would try the following

```
Concat(left(Code.Description,30),IIF(Len(Code.Description)>30,'...',''))
```

or even

```
left(Code.Description,30)+IIF(Len(Code.Description)>30,'...','')
```

> **EDIT**

As you can see the same execution plan, however, the performance of my approach was 18% better.  This test was done on an isolated machine with a sample size of 30,000 records.

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Harder to read and requires more processing... his lead would probably love it.

Comment: Just FYI, `iif()` optimizes into `case`. Just like `nullif()` does.

Comment: @MatthewWhited Harder to read is debatable, but it turns out that the non CASE was 18% faster (see edit to my answer).  For the record, I was prepared to see inverse.

Comment: What percentage of your descriptions were longer than 30 char.

Comment: @MatthewWhited Exactly 50%

Comment: Interesting... I'd still go with the case statement and I'm not (currently) bored enough to try to reproduce your results.  BTW, is this mixed lengths of just two different string repeated 15k times?

Comment: @MatthewWhited You caught me, I was bored.   They were mixed l

Comment: Nah, I would be curious too (I kinda am and may even run this test myself)  but even on the max lens `15k*29 + 15k*50` this would be just over 1 MB of data and with how massive our machines are anymore I'm not sure we could get reliable data on this small of a dataset.  (an arduino has enough horse power to run this test pretty quickly.)